# The shipment couldn't be saved. {"exception":"[object]

Tags: magento2

The shipment couldn't be saved. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(code: 0): The shipment couldn't be saved. at /vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/ShipmentRepository.php:150, Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): Not all of your products are available in the requested quantity. at /vendor/magento/module-inventory-source-deduction-api/Model/SourceDeductionService.php:86)"} []

Answer (score 0):

Just checked the product Qty you have in source item table

```
mysql-> select * from inventory_source_item where sku = %your sku%;
```

Just check the product Qty you have in legacy Catalog Inventory Stock Item table

```
  mysql-> select * from cataloginventory_stock_item where product_id = %your product id%
```

If the Qty item is zero in the inventory_source_item update the Quantity item . Then issue will be solved.

Comment: i am getting this error in log after every second in exception log

Comment: if youare working any cronjob for this ?

Comment: not sure but i have 2 enviorment 1 is stage not getting there but getting on live